# Is this really an integer solution to $n^{1.01} = n*\ln(n)$

Tags: logarithms, integers

Wolfram alpha [says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E1.01+%3D+n*log(n)) a very large number ($n > 10^{100}$) is an integer solution to $ n^{1.01} = n*\ln(n) $. I'm skeptical and have no way computationally viable way to verify this. Is it true?

Comment: This is definitely incorrect. $\log n$ is transcendental for any integer $n$.

Comment: Note that this would be equivalent to claiming that $(\log n)^{100}$ is an integer, which is not possible as @Wojowu indicates

Comment: @Wojowu except for $n=1$, which is however no solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion turns out to be correct - this equation definitely has no integer solution. To see why this is the case, we note that for any integer $n$, $n^{1.01}$ is an algebraic number, but $\ln(n)$ is a transcendental number for any integer $n>1$m as a corollary to the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) (indeed, if $\ln(n)\neq 0$ was algebraic, $n=e^{\ln n}$ would be transcendental by the theorem).

Let this be a warning for everyone not to take Wolfram Alpha's word for granted!

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha has mistook a near-integer for an integer due to its finite precision. I wonder what it would make of $\exp\pi\sqrt{163}$, another famous near-integer. As has been noted, $\ln n$ being transcendental prevents positive integer solutions. However, if we define $n\ln n$ at $n=0$ by continuity, that gives us an uninteresting integer solution.

Comment: WA very easily deals with $\exp\pi\sqrt{163}$ - this differs from an integer at a 30th decimal place, which is accuracy WA can easily work with

Comment: @Wojowu I thought it might. It's a shame [I couldn't have made the challenge harder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number).

Comment: I wonder how far the actual value of n is to an integer ?

Comment: @SamRosen Maybe WA would let you wrap $n$ in [the function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) $\{\}$ (the notation I'm used to, but Wikipedia doesn't mention it) to find out. Be warned the answer could be very close to $1$ instead of being very small.

Comment: @SamRosen Is the solution $$1.285440303215859839556321872\cdot 10^{281}$$ ? If so, it is not at all near an integer. The fractional part is $$0.672857721582\dots $$

Answer (score 0):

What Wolfram Alpha provides is one of  the solutions, in the real domain, of
$$n^{a}=\log(n)\qquad \text{where} \qquad a=\frac 1 {100}$$ which are 
$$n_1=\left(-\frac{W_0(-a)}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}\qquad \text{and} \qquad n_2=\left(-\frac{W_{-1}(-a)}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}$$ For this specific value of $a$, $n_1\approx 2.74602$ and $n_2\approx 1.28544\times 10^{281}$.

Using illimited precision
$$n_2-\text{Round}[n_2]\approx -0.327$$